# uninitialized constant error when run my rake task, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a class which is NOT an ActiveRecord.
the class is located under lib/room/

**lib/room/car_painter.rb**

```
class ROOM::CarPainter

  def paint_car
    ...
  end

end
```

Then, I have a rake task:
under /lib/tasks/

**/lib/tasks/new_car_painting.rake**

```
namespace :new_car do

  desc "Paint new cars"
  task :paint => :environment do
    painter = ROOM::CarPainter.new #ERROR HERE- uninitialized constant
    painter.paint_car
  end

end
```

When I run **rake new_car:paint**, I got the error message "**uninitialized constant ROOM::CarPainter**", Why??

**--EDIT--**-

I also tried to use class function instead of instance function, like following:

```
class ROOM::CarPainter

   def self.paint_car
        ...
   end

end
```

and

namespace :new_car do

```
  desc "Paint new cars"
  task :paint => :environment do
    ROOM::CarPainter.paint_car #ERROR HERE- uninitialized constant
  end

end
```

But I get the same error message...why again

Comment: require `lib/room/car_painter`

Comment: No, it conplains "undefined local variable or method `lib' for main:Object"

Comment: include that module as shown in answer post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is rake file.

```
desc 'This is just a testing rake task'
  task :update_ts => :environment do |t,args|
  puts 'ashish is great'
  include TestLib
  print_sm
end
```

This is lib/test_lib.rb file.

```
module TestLib
 def print_sm
  puts "Hello World in Lib Directory"
 end
end
```

You just need to include that module.

Edited:

I guess problem is your lib/* folder loading.
Try with this in your application.rb file:

```
 config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Comment: Hi, I followed exactly the same style as you did, but still the same error message pop up...:(

Comment: yeah..in Rails 3, lib folder is not in the autoload path by default..you need to add that in the `environment.rb` file..in Rails 2 it is autoloaded by default.

Answer (score 0):

In rails you need to require from the root and rails 3 practice is the following

```
require Rails.root.join('path')
```